# ViewController moves a few pixels up when loaded again

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross, viewcontroller, sidebar

I'm using Xamarin.iOS, MvvmCross and the Xamarin Sidebar (as a support lib by mvvmcross)

When starting the app for the first time, everything seems normal the center viewcontroller is correctly placed and a opaque/non-translucent navigationbar is showed.

When navigating to another viewcontroller the the view is slightly upwards as you can see in these images:

**First time viewing viewcontroller**

[image: First time viewing viewcontroller]

**Second time viewing viewcontroller**

[image: Second time viewing viewcontroller]

The strange thing is that when the viewcontroller is positioned underneath the navigationbar and I rotate the screen from landscape and back to portrait, the view **does** show at the right height

I've tried many solutions:

```
EdgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None;
```

And

```
NavigationController.View.SetNeedsLayout();
NavigationController.View.LayoutIfNeeded();
```

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

```
ToggleStatusBarHiddenOnOpen = true
```

it's a property on the xamarin sidebar.

this option took me 5 hours to find... because this was set to 'true' when the menu was open the view missed 20 px from the statusbar since it was hidden.

not using this option solved my problem